# How to access another cells on the same row based on cell change?

Tags: excel, vba

I change the value in the cell and I would like to print/get the cell on the same row but on different column. Here is the example:

```
Col1 Col2

a   
b    10
c
```

When I add 10 to the third row Col2, I would like to see a message box with value on Col1 third row, which is "b".

Rows index shouldn't be limited to 3 as in the example.

Edited: I will add some value on any cell  under Col2, and I would like a macro to add this value to the left column automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Worksheet.Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) in your desired worksheet. It triggers on every change of any cell. You can use the [Application.Intersect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) to limit your code to trigger on changces in column 2.

Finally you can use the [Range.Offset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) to move from the cell that was changed to another column by setting the `ColumnOffset` parameter. Negative values move left positive right of the current cell.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(2)) 'check if the change was in column 2

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then 'run the code only if column 2 was changed
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange 'run this code for every cell in column 2 that  was changed
            If Cell.Value = 10 Then 'test if the cell was changed to 10
                MsgBox Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value 'return the value of the cell one left (-1) of the cell that was changed
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Cells(yourRange.Row, anyColumnNumberYouWish)
```

or

```
Cells(Range("B3").Row, 1)
```

Comment: I will add some value on any cell  under col2, and I would like a macro to add this value to the left column automatically.